# List all index of all characters in a string in Java 8

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given a string want a map of list where the key will be each character and value will be a list of integers indicating indexes where the character is present.\
I want to do it in Java 8

Input: `standard`

Output:

```
s - 0
t - 1
a - 2,5
n - 3
d - 4,7
r - 6
```

Answer (score 2):

A neat trick you can use is to stream the indices of the string, and then collect them by the character at that index:

```java
Map<Character, List<Integer>> indices =
    IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(input::charAt));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the order of insertion, a `LinkedHashMap` has to be used when grouping the indexes by character:

```java
String input = "standard";
Map<Character, List<Integer>> charIndexes =
    IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 input::charAt, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()
            ));
```

Similar solution without using Stream API:

```java
Map<Character, List<Integer>> charIndexes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0, n = input.length(); i < n; i++) {
    charIndexes.computeIfAbsent(input.charAt(i), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
```

Then the contents of the map may be printed like this:

```java
charIndexes.forEach((c, ix) -> System.out.println(
    c + " - " + ix.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
));
```

Output

```
s - 0
t - 1
a - 2,5
n - 3
d - 4,7
r - 6
```